# Finding matching symbols in a string

Tags: c

As stated above need to find all the duplicated elements in a string ( user inserted string ). I know the most part of the code and how it should look, BUT the thing that caught me off is, HOW do you compare symbols in a single string?
for example if the string would be:

"ABCDEFGACFA"

Result should be:

"CF"

Only idea I had so far:

```
for(i=0;i<stringLenght; ++i)
  {
  for(j=i+1; j < stringLenght; ++j)
     {
     if(string[i]==[string[j]
      // ..........
```

Comment: Either I didn't get your question or if I am right, output should be "ACF"

Comment: Do you know what the string to be searched for will be? Or is it guessing based on what it reads? How did you get "CF"?

Comment: Yeah my bad, kinda sleepy so hard to express my thoughts, basicly: the symbol can repeat only once otherwise it should be ignored.

Comment: So it's not really "matching" characters but instead "duplicated" characters?

Comment: Good point, edit to the rescue. Thanks!

Comment: I thought about it, but had problems implementing it to work on one string, mind giving an example?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question, but I have an idea that can help you to identify repeated symbols.

using a "map" can solve this problem, for example: let's suppose that we are working with uppercase characters only, so we can use an integer array to simulate the mapping, if an element in your map is bigger than one, then that element is repeated in your string.

here is my code in C++ that obtain that map:

```
string str;
int myMap[26]; //an element for each uppercase character
memset(myMap, 0, sizeof myMap); // initialize each element to zero
cin>>str;
for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
{
    //(str[i]-'A') will map each character to an integer
    // A -> 0, B -> 1, C -> 2, etc.
    myMap[(int)(str[i]-'A')]++;
}
//print solution:
for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
{
    if(myMap[i] > 1)
    {
        cout<<(char)(i+'A')<<" is repeated!"<<endl;
    }
}
```

for your example, the output will be:

```
A is repeated!
C is repeated!
F is repeated!
```